# launching a UIViewcontroller from a UITableViewController crashes app

Tags: iphone, ios5, storyboard, segue

I have a UItableViewController. Inside this class there is the following method where I am trying to launch another UIViewController. I tried to connect the two using a segue and gave it a identifier, then used this version:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    NSLog(@"About to launch MyDetail View controller");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myDetailSegue" sender:self];
}
```

That didnt work, the app froze and I got a message in the main.m file as follows: "    "Thread 1 received signal Sigabrt"

So then deleted the segue and tried to instantiate the UIViewcontroller as follows,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"About to launch my Detail View controller");
    UIStoryboard *sboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *myDetailVC = [sboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myDetailVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myDetailVC animated:YES];
}
```

which worked. But now Im confused. Why would the UIStoryboard way work and the segue not???
Could someone please help, Im so confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get understand what exactly problem you are facing but i want tell you that because of you are using uitableview first please connect its cell to new view controller and select 'Push' segue method. Once you have done this then add following code in your application instead to user **didselectrowatindexpath** methods.

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

  /*
   When a row is selected, the segue creates the detail view controller as the destination.
   Set the detail view controller's detail item to the item associated with the selected row.
   */
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Showcategorydetails"]) {

  ```
  NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
  CategoryDetailsController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
  detailViewController.category_title = [maincategories_array objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
  ```

  }
  }

Comment: Thanks. the problem was that the destination Viewcontroller was crashing because the outlet connections were all messed up. I had copied that ViewController on the storyboard from another View Controller and it also copied the outlet connections. So this copy of the ViewController was connected to the outlets of the old Viewcontroller. Once this was fixed, I was good to go.

Thanks